# Python ThreadPoolExecutor and closed connections

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading

I'm doing some threaded requests that pull JSON data down from an API.  There would be anywhere from 5 to 15 concurrent calls happening.  I wrote this script that works fine for most instances of where I'm running it.  The futures get shoved into a list, and then I can iterate over the returned data and do the dataframe work that needs to happen.  (What comes back is JSON, but I don't think that's important for what is broken here.)

Where it fails is when one of the requests takes a lot longer than the others.  What bubbles up is this:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1322, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

What I *think* this means is that because the first request (which can sometimes be completed in under a second) finished so long ago, the longest ones (maybe 2 minutes or more) are having their connection terminated before they finish.  When I run this long request individually in Postman, it finishes just fine.  It's just when I have these short little requests in front of it that it dies on me.

Is there a way to keep the connection alive?  Or to keep from using connections that are shared between threads?

Stripped code below.  It looks pretty close to this.

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import datetime

def download(url):
    starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
    with requests.get(url) as response:
        runtime = round(datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(datetime.datetime.now() - starttime))

        status_code = response.status_code
        reason = response.reason
        text = response.text            

    print(f"Downloaded {url} (in {str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=runtime))})")

    return status_code, reason, text    

urls = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://stackoverflow.com"
]   

futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for url in urls:        
        futures.append( {"endpoint": url, "result": executor.submit(download, url) } )  

for future in futures:
    result = future['result'].result()
    print( result[0], result[1] )
```

Comment: I am having similar issue, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @user1491687 No, unfortunately.

Comment: Found this answer having more details about gracefully cancelling the outstanding tasks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923690/does-concurrent-futures-as-completed-yield-for-cancelled-futures