# Does concurrent.futures.as_completed yield for cancelled futures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I'm using the ThreadPoolExecutor to do multiple tasks at the same time and this question is about gracefully cancelling the outstanding tasks.
It seems to me that when I cancel outstanding (i.e. not yet running) futures, concurrent.futures.as_completed never yields the cancelled futures. Even though its documentation states "[as_completed] yields futures as they complete (finished or cancelled futures)."

Example:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_task(t):
    time.sleep(t)
    print('task',t,'finished')
    return t

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    future_to_t = {executor.submit(do_task, t): t for t in range(1,6)}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_t):
        print('tasks done?',[f.done() for f in future_to_t])
        t = future_to_t[future]
        if t == 1:
            executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)
            print('outstanding tasks are now cancelled')
    print('all tasks done')
print('bye')
```

In the example I put 5 tasks in the pipeline and cancel them after the first task completes. Since tasks 2, 3 and 4 already started (3 workers) I expect task 5 to be cancelled and yielded by as_completed - but that never happens. The above code prints:

```
task 1 finished
tasks done? [True, False, False, False, False]
outstanding tasks are now cancelled
task 2 finished
tasks done? [True, True, False, False, True]
task 3 finished
tasks done? [True, True, True, False, True]
task 4 finished
tasks done? [True, True, True, True, True]
```

It then hangs and never reaches `all tasks done`.

I can get around this problem by checking the states of the futures and breaking the loop once all futures are completed - but that's what I expect from as_completed.

What am I doing wrong? Any insights? Thanks!

Follow-up:

- If I use `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()` to cancel the futures their state changes to `CANCELLED`, but not to `CANCELLED_AND_NOTIFIED` as expected by `concurrent.futures.as_completed()`.
- `concurrent.futures.as_completed()` works as expected if I cancel the futures myself.
- So, as a workaround I use
  `for f in future_to_t: f.cancel()` instead of `executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and wanted to use `executor.shutdown()` as well. If you don't mind going through the futures sequentially, rather than using `as_completed()` and getting futures by time of completion, you can use a `for` loop and check for status instead

```
for future in futures:
    if future.cancelled():
        pass
    result = future.result()
```